# Froala textarea showing when I try to overlay with a semi-transparent mask

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, froala

The page I am working on displays a semi-transparent overlay to "grey-out" the screen with a light colored message. This overly & message is displayed whenever it is waiting for a background process to finish.  This has been working very well, until I added the Froala text editor.

Technical details: Angular 1.5.8, 
Angular Material Design 1.1.3 - I am testing the upgrade to this version, which is when I noticed the problem with the froala editor conflict
Froala Version 2 (just pulled last month)
angular-froala v. 2.4.2

We create a div with css that sets the background to background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)  and a second div with the message in white letters & a light image.

When activated, the screen is greyed-out everywhere but the textarea with the froala directive, which remains white.  Setting the z-index works on making the foreground of the two overlay divs show up, but doesn't affect the froala textarea.  I've tried setting the z-index on every directive involved, setting the froala z-index option, and setting the froala iframe option to false.

Any ideas for other things to try?

Comment: Move your overlay `div` to last position in `body` tag.  I don't know froala, but I'd assume it could be adding markup itself, so you might have to make that move once the page finishes rendering, via javascript

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - it turns out that the item I was trying to gray out was actually a child of the div that was having its background set to do the "graying out"

At least I wasn't the only person who missed it - I asked two of the other developers who worked on this to help me and they missed it as well